# Isaac's Blessing

Tags: isaac

In Genesis 27, Isaac states he wants to give the blessing before he dies....
Rebekah repeats that in urging Jacob to go on with the ruse....

What puzzles me is Rebekah's lack of empathy for her husband's impending death.

She seems only concerned with the stealing of the blessing and not of the death of her husband who she had to be married to for a good many years.

Anyone care to explain her lack of feeling here?

Answer (score 3):

Isaac loved his elder son's venison. The venison of the macho, hairy hunter. But what of the plain man dwelling in tents ?

And why did Rebekah enquire of the Lord regarding the striving within her as she bore the twins ? Why not go to Isaac and ask her husband ?

But Isaac's eyes were clouded.

The promise was to Rebekah. And the promise was that the elder hairy huntsman with his lovely venison *would serve the younger*.

All of this has spiritual import. Sometimes an older generation rests content with nature. Spiritually, their eyes are darkened.

And, sometimes, one will have to circumvent nature in order to reach for what is spiritual : to reach for something better in a coming generation.

Thus for Rebekah and Jacob. Thus for what they had to do to inherit the blessing (*which was already promised to Jacob*). For Esau was not the seed of promise.

Isaac's eyes were dim and he favoured his huntsman son.

And he loved his venison.

Comment: +1 I particularly appreciate your insight that "the promise was to Rebekah." I hadn't included that in my considerations previously.

Answer (score 3):

Isaac was 60 years of age when he fathered Jacob and Esau, the twins, born of Rebekah. Isaac was 180 years of age when he died. Those facts can be gleaned from Genesis 25:26 and 35:28-29.

It's worth pondering the age factor here, because not only was Isaac extremely old, Rebekah must have been approaching 140 years of age herself (at least) given that Jacob and Esau were 120 years of age at the time of their father's death.

People who are less than 100 years of age cannot grasp the feelings of those three parties (the father, the mother and the twins) who were all over 100 years of age. Nor is this about feelings.

Young people today are inclined to suppose that how they feel is how other people should feel. Well, the Bible does not set store on personal feelings, but on duty, and respect for the aged by those younger than their elders.

Rebekah managed to show both respect for her dying husband, and commitment to God's promise to her, 120 years previously, that the older son would serve the younger. She stole nothing. Her younger son stole nothing. The birthright was God-given. Rebekah - in faith - ensured the securing of it, to Jacob. This was all in God's will. There's no case for trying to explore Rebekah's apparent lack of empathy or feelings, as modern people would view it, because we know nothing of what she was going through, as a very old woman aged about 140 years.

Comment: @Dan Fefferman - quite correct! My mistake which I shall immediately rectify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't read into Isaac's words any suggestion that his death was obviously imminent, in terms of the next day or two. It reads more like a general sense that his death can't be far away, perhaps in the next couple of years. This is the equivalent of recognising that it really is time that he made his will. In fact Isaac is around long enough to send Jacob away in the next chapter.

Nor do I think that the writer of Genesis would have felt the need to record everything that the characters said or felt. His business is to tell the basic story.

Comment: Isaac is reported to have said  ‘See, I am old; I do not know the day of my death."  In modern terms we can think of this as making his will at age 60.

Answer (score 0):

Rebekah's supposed lack of empathy for Isaac is explained by her awareness that God wanted the blessing to go to Jacob. The verse that immediately precedes this incident (at the end of Gen. 26) shows why:

> 34 When Esau was forty years old, he married Judith daughter of Beeri
> the Hittite, and Basemath daughter of Elon the Hittite; 35 and they
> made life bitter for Isaac and Rebekah.

Although Rebekah deceived Isaac into blessing Esau, the two were united in their belief that Esau must not marry outside of the Hebrew lineage. Thus, at the beginning of chapter 28 we read:

> Isaac called Jacob and blessed him, and charged him, ‘You shall not
> marry one of the Canaanite women. 2 Go at once to Paddan-aram to the
> house of Bethuel, your mother’s father; and take as wife from there
> one of the daughters of Laban, your mother’s brother. 3 May God
> Almighty bless you and make you fruitful and numerous, that you may
> become a company of peoples.

*Esau had disqualified himself from the elder son's blessing, first by despising his birthright (25:34) and then by marrying two Hittite women.*

Also @Nigel has pointed out, the prophecy that "the elder shall serve the younger" (25:23) was given to Rebekah. She had to put God's will ahead of her husband's preference. In that sense his physical blindness was probably not accidental, by a symptom of his spiritual condition regarding which son should receive the primary blessing.

**Conclusion: we are not told Rebekah's internal attitude toward Isaac in this story, but we can understand that she was God's agent in fulfilling Jacob's destiny. The fact the couple immediately united in blessing Jacob again and sending him find a wife in Haran shows and if there was any enmity between them, it did not last.**

Answer (score 0):

Isaac was far from his actual death when he gave blessing to his sons. He felt his death was imminent for his eyes were weak, so he gave his sons the father's blessing earlier than it should. We read "Isaac, who had a taste for wild game, loved Esau, but Rebekah loved Jacob." (Gen 25:28 NIV) Later, we read "The wives of Esau were a source of grief to Isaac and Rebekah" (Gen 26:35)

The love between Isaac and Rebekah can be seen in Gen 26:8

> 8 When Isaac had been there a long time, Abimelech king of the Philistines looked down from a window and saw Isaac caressing his wife Rebekah. (NIV)

So what was in mind of Rebekah that she planned to steal the blessing from Esau to Jacob?

Consider it was a society of patriarchy. If Rebekah lost Isaac, she would definitely live on Jacob rather than Esau. It was not Rebekah's lack of empathy to Isaac, but her rational choice. Perhaps both Isaac and Rebekah did not know Esau had despised his birthright for just a bowl of red stew (Gen 25:29-34), and Esau lost his blessing as a consequence of his choice.

Though the scripture had not explicitly explained, it is for sure the history of Israel would not be the same if Isaac was not losing his sight and gave the blessing early.